# C++ Recursion - How to ensure I don't repeat the same values

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, c++11, recursion

My goal is to look at two arrays (each having four items) and put any value that appears in both of them in a vector.

Technically, I can just use a loop, like

```
vector<int> result;

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        if (array1[i] == array2[j] {
                result.push_back(array1[l]);
        }
    }
}
```

But having recently learned recursion, I wanted to try solving this problem using a recursive algorithm.

```
void findOverLaps(int array1[4], int array2[4], int startIndex1, int startIndex2, vector<int> *resultVector) {
    if (startIndex1 > 3 || startIndex2 > 3) {
        return;
    }
    if (array1[startIndex1] == array2[startIndex2]) {
        resultVector->push_back(array1[startIndex1]);
    }

    findOverLaps(array1, array2, startIndex1 + 1, startIndex2, resultVector);
    findOverLaps(array1, array2, startIndex1, startIndex2 + 1, resultVector);
}

int main() {
    vector<int> result;
    findOverLaps(array1, array2, 0, 0, &result);
}
```

This code does find all the similar values. The problem is this recursive algorithm finds those same values multiple times even though they appear only once in each array.

For example, if I pass in two arrays: {1, 2, 3, 4} and {5, 6, 2, 8}, into the recursive function, the function recognizes the repetition of 2 three times. However, I only want it to see it as one since 2 only reappeared once.

I understand why this repetition exists. When I increment the index of the second array, even though it goes through a new recursion, I am still allowing the first index to change, like in the previous recursion. So incrementing the index branches off unnecessary additional recursions.

I don't know how to solve it. Can someone help me with this please.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious way to use recursion would be to use a recursive sorting algorithm (e.g., QuickSort or a top-down merge sort) to sort both arrays before using `std::set_intersection` on the two sorted arrays.

Unfortunately, with only 4 items in each array, neither QuickSort nor a merge sort is really particularly optimal. You'd be better off with an insertion sort, which isn't nearly as amenable to a recursive implementation (though yes, it could be done if you wanted to badly enough).

The algorithm you're using right now has O(N<sup>2</sup>) complexity. That's fairly harmless as long as you're only dealing with a tiny number of items, but if you might need to deal with a large number of items (e.g., hundreds in each array), the O(N log N) complexity of using a sort followed by `set_intersection` will make a huge difference.

Bottom line: recursion is cool and all, but it doesn't strike me as a particularly great approach to this particular problem. It could be used and make to work correctly, but I'm not particularly convinced that doing so will accomplish much.

Answer (score 1):

As Jerry already pointed out in his answer, I also think that sorting and using `std::set_intersection` is the way to do this in the general case.

Just to add a solution to your recursive function, you could do it like this.

```
void findOverLaps(int array1[4], int array2[4], int startIndex1, int startIndex2, vector<int> *resultVector) {
    if (startIndex2 > 3) {
        startIndex1++;
        startIndex2 = 0;
    }
    if (startIndex1 > 3) {
        return;
    }
    if (array1[startIndex1] == array2[startIndex2]) {
        resultVector->push_back(array1[startIndex1]);
    }

    findOverLaps(array1, array2, startIndex1, startIndex2 + 1, resultVector);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When your recursive function reaches the range limit of an index, it does not reset that index, but returns to where it was called from. Super's solution already solves this in a way. Just for fun, I am adding a solution in which indices are changed only in the calls to the recursive function, and never within the function itself:

```
void findOverLaps(int array1[4], int array2[4], int startIndex1, int startIndex2, vector<int> *resultVector) {

    if (startIndex2 > 3) {
        findOverLaps(array1, array2, startIndex1+1, 0, resultVector);
    }
    if (startIndex1 > 3 || startIndex2 > 3) {
        return;
    }
    if (array1[startIndex1] == array2[startIndex2]) {
        resultVector->push_back(array1[startIndex1]);
    }

    findOverLaps(array1, array2, startIndex1, startIndex2 + 1, resultVector);
}
```